# Modsecurity 3rd party cookie handling

Tags: security, mod-security

I recently installed modsecurity in my web server. My website contains some 3rd party cookies like google analytics, adroller, etc... Modsecurity blocks some of these cookies sometimes.

```
 
Is there is a way to disable modsecurity for these 3rd party cookies ?
```

```
Can I set a cookie list which required to check by modsecurity ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you usually just have to see which rules flag and then turn off those rules or turn them off for that particular argument. This involves adding config like this to your Apache config:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981172 !REQUEST_COOKIES:'/^__utm/'
```

More details of all the commands here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual

Recommendation is to run in DetectionOnly mode for a bit to identify all the false positives.

I'm not aware of any big list of all the tweaks you'd need to put in place depending which software you use. Not a bad idea to set this up.

Then again it would be nice if the rules were updated with common software like Google in mind. Though nothing to stop you (or me!) doing this ourselves by suggesting fixes to the free Core Rule Set which most people use: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs